# Why all values in torch tensor change

Tags: pytorch

I am writing a class inherited from torch.autograd.Function, but I found something wrong with the output_grad in backward function. It seems that output_grad is a tensor of size 8 but with just only 1 element in memory since all the values are the same. But such techniques are not observed in other torch.autograd.Function classes. I wonder what could be the problem.

```
class FusedRotaryEmbeddingFunction(torch.autograd.Function):
@staticmethod
def forward(ctx, x, cos, sin, position_ids, tensor_index, k_size, rotary_size, base):
    ctx.save_for_backward(cos, sin, position_ids)
    ctx.tensor_index = tensor_index
    ctx.k_size = k_size
    ctx.rotary_size = rotary_size
    ctx.base = base
    return fused_apply_rotary_emb_cuda.forward(x, cos, sin, position_ids, tensor_index, k_size, rotary_size, base)

@staticmethod
def backward(ctx, output_grad):
    cos, sin, position_ids = ctx.saved_tensors
    tensor_index = ctx.tensor_index
    k_size = ctx.k_size
    rotary_size = ctx.rotary_size
    base = ctx.base

    print(output_grad.nelement())

    print(output_grad.shape, output_grad, type(output_grad))
    output_grad[0, 0, 0, 5] = 10
    print(output_grad)

    x_grad = fused_apply_rotary_emb_cuda.backward(output_grad, cos, sin, position_ids, tensor_index, k_size, rotary_size, base)

    return (x_grad, None, None, None, None, None, None, None)
```

the print produces

```
8
torch.Size([1, 1, 1, 8]) tensor([[[[1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]]]], device='cuda:0', dtype=torch.float16) <class 'torch.Tensor'>
tensor([[[[10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10., 10.]]]], device='cuda:0', dtype=torch.float16)
```